# Razor javascript filling limit

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have some problem with javascript limit. I am using Razor and filling javascript array with razor like this:`

```
var KriterAlanlariHtml = new Array();

@{
    int sayac = 0;
    string html = "";
    foreach (var group in Model.GrupDTO)
    {
         if (group != null && group.ListAreaDTO != null)
            {


                foreach (var area in group.ListAreaDTO)
                {
                    html = BuildHtmlTag(area);

                    <text>
                    KriterAlanlariHtml[@sayac] = "@MvcHtmlString.Create(html)";
                    </text>

                    sayac++;
                }

    }

}

}
```

`

After this codes View.cshtml filling Javascript array with html codes. But I couldnt this array in JavaScript. Because of javascript limitations. If I check the elements on Chrome, I am seeing like screenshot-1.

[Screenshoot-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PjGkx.jpg)

[Screenshoot-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Iri9.jpg)

I coulndt use like this code: KriterAlanlariHtml[25] .Chrome giving this error:
 **KriterAlanlariHtml is not defined**

How can i solve this problem ? (HTML is not wrong.)

Comment: Razor is server side code - its executed before anything is sent to the client. Javascript is client side code - it does not even exist when you code is executed

Comment: I just try to fill an javascript array with razor. Its possible with razor.  @programtreasures give solution. Its below.  If I write every array element in <script></script> tag its working.

Comment: Your misunderstanding how the code in that answer works :)  - its use `<text>` tags to write out the script in the server. But your code is awful practice. That code does not belong in the view. And to convert a collection in your model to a javascript array, its just `var groups = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.GrupDTO))` inside your script (one line of code). But you pass the right values to the view in the first place, not by using methods in the view to convert it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add javascript code inside script tag, the updated code is below

```
    <script>
    var KriterAlanlariHtml = new Array();
</script>

@{
    int sayac = 0;
    string html = "";
    foreach (var group in Model.GrupDTO)
    {
         if (group != null && group.ListAreaDTO != null)
            {
                foreach (var area in group.ListAreaDTO)
                {
                    html = BuildHtmlTag(area);
                        <script>
                            KriterAlanlariHtml[@sayac] = "@MvcHtmlString.Create(html)";
                        </script>
                    sayac++;
                }
            }
    }

}
```

Comment: Wait a minute... Now I understood what did you say. I write every array element in <script></script> tag.  Its working now.. Thank you very much..